# Mongodb query for embedded doc

Tags: spring, mongodb, hashmap, spring-mongo

I am having trouble to query that, I want to find all the docs that contains the id "5418a26ce4b0e4a40ea1d548" in the individualUsers field. would be esp useful if you know how to do that in Spring Data MongoDB query.

db.collection.find({individualUser:{"5418a26ce4b0e4a40ea1d548"}})

example of one doc

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5418c3b9e4b03feec4345602"), "creatorId" : "5418a214e4b0e4a40ea1d546", "individualUsers" : { "5418a26ce4b0e4a40ea1d548" : null, "5418a278e4b0e4a40ea1d54a" : null } }
```

### Update #001

Entity code

```
@Document
class Idea{
  @Id
  String id;
  String creatorId;
  Map<String,String> individualUsers;
  /*getter and setter omitted*/
}
```

Interface

```
public interface IdeaRepository extends MongoRepository<Idea,String> {
}
```

### Update #002

So when spring-mongodb saves hashmap to json, it will look like

```
"individualUsers" : { "5418a26ce4b0e4a40ea1d548" : null, "5418a278e4b0e4a40ea1d54a" : null }
```

In java program I can easily get the data using the key value. but in the mongodb query, I can't query the key?

so the question is can I query inside the "individualUsers": {} with the key ??

Comment: Those are the key names and not values. I would suggest that whatever code is creating this is doing it wrong. This likely should be an array of `ObjectId` types. Same goes for `creatorId` which has also been allowed to stringify.

Comment: care to share with us what is your JPA implementation? and then your Entities code

Comment: @BillyFrost - basically the individualUsers is a HashMap<String,String>. and I am using MongoRepository, i think that's all that matter? thanks.

Comment: @NeilLunn - can we query the key names?

Comment: MongoRepository is not a JPA implementation. It is Spring MongoDB, which is not JPA